# Do touch spells deserve a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

So I noticed when I was writing an answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53164/4563) that we have a lot of questions about “touch attacks,” which are used for certain magic abilities in D&D that require touching the target. I imagine other systems could easily have analogous options. It seems to be a confusing topic, and we have several questions about it.

At what point (and why) does it become useful to add a tag for something like this? Someone searching “touch attack” would probably get everything in the tag anyway, without a lot of  false-positives, and obviously there hasn’t been emergent usage of such a tag. Still, I wanted, when writing my answer above, to be able to link to those questions – a tag would have been useful for that purpose. Instead I referenced the Related questions on the right.

So, does this topic deserve a tag of its own? Are there any guidelines for when something like this crosses the line from “something a fair few questions have been asked about” to a real “specific topic that deserves a tag of its own”?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd say this deserves a tag, yeah.

> At what point (and why) does it become useful to add a tag for something like this?

It becomes useful to create a tag when someone says: ‘hey, it'd be useful to have a tag about this,’ and creates it. There's not many clear rules of thumb around them, since they're mostly done by feel, but this passes as being a good tag. It's a distinct and clear topic area, people can actually have expertise on it here, etc.

> Are there any guidelines for when something like this crosses the line from “something a fair few questions have been asked about” to a real “specific topic that deserves a tag of its own”?

There aren't really, given the *really loose* basis on which tags get created. But you're dealing with a tag that would collect a bunch of questions on one clear topic together to make them more accessible, so it offers plenty of utility as a tag.

Comment: +1.  "It deserves a tag if you bothered to create one.  It doesn't if you didn't."

Comment: Who first said: "Tagging is an emergent folksonomy"?

Answer (score -2):

I'd argue **against** creating a tag for such a narrow topic.

Think of it this way. **Tags help other users of the site keep up with questions they are interested in.** You say things like *"Hey, I'm an expert on `tag-x` so I'll add it to my favorites list and try to help people with it"* or *"I'd like to learn more about `tag-y` so I'll keep an eye on it."* or even *"I'm fed up with all this `tag-z` clutter, I'll add that to my ignore list"*

When creating a tag, I ask myself the question: **Would someone add it to their favorite or ignored tags list?** If yes, then it may be a candidate for consideration. If no, then dropping it is probably the best idea.

So ask yourself the same question; would you like to follow or ignore all `touch-attack` questions?

I wouldnt…

Comment: Follow or ignore, probably not. Do a search for, or link to the group? Yes, those I would do.

Comment: @KRyan as you pointed out, search does work without tags. So does a link to a search page. I see it as unnecessary clutter in the tagspace. Maybe you would want to follow `touch-attack` and that's ok. Then do create it and see if it picks up. Maybe it does prove useful.